# What a problem with this buttom in windows form and sqlconnection

Tags: c#

Details:

> System.InvalidOperationException
> HResult=0x80131509
> Message=BeginExecuteNonQuery requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed.
> Source=System.Data.SqlClient
> StackTrace:
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ValidateCommand(Boolean async, String method)
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite, String methodName) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.BeginExecuteNonQuery(AsyncCallback callback, Object stateObject) at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncImpl(Func`3 beginMethod, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Object state, TaskCreationOptions creationOptions) at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsync(Func`3 beginMethod, Func`2 endMethod, Object state)
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQueryAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
> at Praktika.Form1.<button2_Click>d__9.MoveNext() in D:\Programminng\практика\Praktika\Praktika\Form1.cs:line 149

This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
[External Code]
Praktika.Form1.button2_Click(object, System.EventArgs) in Form1.cs

```
 private async void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (label8.Visible)
            label8.Visible = false;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox11.Text) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox11.Text) &&
            !string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox6.Text) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox6.Text) &&
            !string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox5.Text) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox5.Text) &&
            !string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox4.Text) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox4.Text))
        {
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("UPDATE [Praktika] SET [LastNAme]=@LastNAme,[Passport]=@Passport,[Cod]=@Cod WHERE [Id]=@Id", sqlConnection);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Id", textBox11);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("LastName", textBox6);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Passport", textBox5);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Cod", textBox4);
            await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
        }
        else if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox11.Text) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox11.Text))
        {
            label8.Visible = true;
            label8.Text = "Id должен быть заполнен!";

        }
        else
        {
            label8.Visible = true;
            label8.Text = "Поля 'Фамилия','Пасспорт и 'Код' должны быть заполнены";
        }

    }
```

[enter image description here][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9oyl.png

Comment: It literally tells you: _"... requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed."_ You need to open a db connection over which the command can work. It's like asking your mum how she's doing without calling her. Doesn't work if she's not in the room.

Comment: and as an answer to your next question, I don't think you want to insert textBox6 into the database, but rather the value in the textbox.

Comment: ^^ ... and there's probably a typo here `SET [LastNAme]` - "NA"? Should be "LastName", no?

Comment: I think I read an article that also discouraged using `AddWithValue` ... will link if I find it again. (3 minutes later... ) I think it was this one: https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> BeginExecuteNonQuery requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed

You need to call `sqlConnection.Open()` before you  `await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();`

I don't recommend holding onto a connection at class level; hold a connection string instead and make a new connection:

```
using var conn = new SqlConnection(classLevelConnStr);
using var command = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
//parameters etc here
conn.Open();
command.Execute...
conn.Close(); //if you're going to do more work before you return, close after you execute
```

If you aren't going to do more work after you execute, you can leave the exiting of the `using` scope to dispose/close the connection. Opening/closing doesn't actually forge a TCP connection to the server, it simply leases and returns a connection from a pool of kept-open TCP connections, for best performance, unless you've turned off pooling (don't).

By holding onto a connection for a long time you can accidentally leave it open (leased), which prevents its re-use, and you can also increase the risk of running into "the connection already has an open reader" type issues if you do something like looping a reader and firing off update queries while you loop; make a new connection every time you want one - it's not a slow thing to create

--

Separately to this:

- Please rename your controls after you drop them on a form. It takes seconds to do and prevents your code filling up with meaningless variable names. The process of filling code with junk variable names is called obfuscation, a technique designed to make code hard to read and understand. At some point someone else will have to read your code (us, your coworker or replacement, even you in 6 months time..) and they would rather read `firstNameTextBox`, `ageNumericUpDown` than `textBox57`, `numericUpDown13`. To understand why it's important, just imagine how confusing C# would be if instead of names like `string.Length, string.Substring(int start, int length)` Microsoft had called them things like `Type1.Integer1, Type1.Method1(Type2 parameter1, Type2 parameter2)` to chop up a string you'd be writing code like `Type1 s = "Hello"; s = s.Method1(0, s.Integer1 - 3);` - it's gobbledegook
- To rename a control, you right click on it, choose Properties, and then type a new name in the `(Name)` line of the property grid - it's at the top. You don't even have to right click if the properties grid is already open, just left click the control
- Avoid using AddWithValue on SQLServer. Some databases don't care, but SQLS does: https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/
- This code is wonky:

  `command.Parameters.AddWithValue("LastName", textBox6);`

  - It should look *something like*:

    `command.Parameters.Add("@LastName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 30).Value = lastNameTextBox.Text);`
  - Replace 30 with the size of the db column and if your column is an NVarChar change the SqlDbType.VarChar to SqlDbType.NVarChar too
  - This latter form implements the "rename your controls", it adds a parameter using the exact type on the DB side, and it sets the value to the Text of the textbox.. This latter point is important; the text the user typed is in the .Text property. If you just add a textbox object itself you'll probably end up filling your db up with `[System.Windows.Forms.TextBox]` in every cell of every row

Comment: _"Please rename your controls after you drop them on a form."_ Extra +1 if I could!

Comment: @Fildor an extension to do just that would be nice